# Scrubyt fetch metadata

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping

How do you fetch the contents of meta name="description" content="....."  with Scrubyt ?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'scrubyt'


data = Scrubyt::Extractor.define do
  fetch 'http://www.allegro.pl/'

  head '//head' do
    description '//meta[@name="description"]'
  end
end

puts data.to_xml
```

What is the the correct way ?

Comment: I only had trouble when I tried to use scrubyt ... have you had a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value of the **content** attribute try:

```
head '//head' do
  description '//meta[@name="description"]/@content'
end
```

`//meta[@name="description"]` selects the meta tag whose *name* attribute is equal to "description" but then you also need to select the value of the *content* attribute.

Comment: It is a standard syntax for selecting attribute values that Scrubyt is using. What you are doing is also similar to the example at http://github.com/scrubber/scrubyt_examples/blob/master/favicon.rb which gets the favicon URL from a page.